# Proof of the multivariate Central Limit Theorem

Tags: central-limit-theorem

Casella and Lerner's "Theory of Point Estimation" (2nd edition) provides a definition of the multivariate Central Limit Theorem, for which no proof is given.

[image]

What would be its derivation?

Comment: If you can refer to the 1-D CLT, then the result automatically follows from [*Cramer-Wold device*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Wold_theorem).